# PowerShell 7 very slow on Network Paths

Tags: powershell, powershell-core, powershell-7.2

Recently I have installed PowerShell 7 as a ZIP package following the guide [Installing PowerShell on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.2#installing-the-zip-package).

(I am forced to install it as a ZIP file because I don't have admin rights on my work computer `:(`.)

Comparing it to the version of PowerShell I already have (5.1.19041.1320), the new version of PowerShell (7.2.1) is incredibly slow when accessing network (UNC) paths.

I am loading both `-noprofile`. While I am in my `HOMESHARE` network directory, I do:

```
Measure-Command { cd . }
```

With PS7, I get 4.2 seconds, with PS5 I get 0.82 seconds.  Any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: Where are your PS7 files installed?  Is it on a network path?  That would explain why PS5 is so much faster.  Are you on a actual computer or some type of Zero or Thin client device and working on a virtual server?  If so, then you are probably not even on the same virtual computer each time you log in.  Anyways, if PS7 isn't installed on the same faster hardware, then we need to figure out if there is a temp folder or something on that hardware we can install PS7 to.  Even if you have to install each time you log in.

Comment: I have unzipped it to the C drive, in my User profile folder.

Comment: It's not possible for me to perfectly recreate your environment, but I did a test of your command using the un-zipped PS-7.2.1 64x from your link and the PS-5.1 already installed on my computer.  I changed to a network drive and my results were in Milliseconds, not seconds.  And PS7 was actually about 8 times faster than PS5.  You might take a look at the APPDATA, HOMEPATH, LOCALAPPDATA, TEMP, TMP, and USERPROFILE environmental variables.  Are they all pointing to the C:\ drive or to a network path.  May also have to look at the folders in C:\Users to see if they are JUNCTION or SYMLINKD.

Comment: I've also seen this problem: my code iterates over large number of files on a Windows Network share, and it is much slower in PS 7 than PS 5. Powershell installed locally, through MS store, and exactly the same code. Did you ever solve this? Maybe it's related to this: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12764 - but I don't thing accessing SMB shares uses HTTP (?)